# How to connect to Password protected SQLite DB with OrmLite?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, orm, ormlite

I copy DB from assets by this code:

```
    public class DatabaseHelper extends OrmLiteSqliteOpenHelper {
        private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "database.db";
        private static final String DATABASE_PATH = "/data/data/"+BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID+"/databases/";

     public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        copyFromAssets(context);
    }

      private void copyFromAssets(Context context) {
        boolean dbexist = checkdatabase();
        if (!dbexist) {
            File dir = new File(DATABASE_PATH);
                dir.mkdirs();
                InputStream myinput = context.getAssets().open(DATABASE_NAME);
                String outfilename = DATABASE_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;
                Log.i(DatabaseHelper.class.getName(), "DB Path : " + outfilename);
                OutputStream myoutput = new FileOutputStream(outfilename);
                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                int length;
                while ((length = myinput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                    myoutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
                }
                myoutput.flush();
                myoutput.close();
                myinput.close();
            }
    }
    }
```

to get Dao I use this:

```
public Dao<AnyItem, Integer> getDaoAnyItem() throws SQLException {
        if (daoAnyItem == null) {
            daoAnyItem = getDao(AnyItem.class);
        }
        return daoAnyItem;
    }
```

**But how to get Dao if my DB will be Password protected?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must use SQLCipher with OrmLite, I would suggest [ormlite-sqlcipher](https://github.com/Andoctorey/ormlite-sqlcipher) library to you

Answer (score 2):

OrmLiteSqliteOpenHelper has a constructor which takes a password so change you super call to

```
super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION, (File)null, "DB password goes here");
```

I would take the call to copyFromAssets(context) out of the DatabaseHelper constructor and call it before DatabaseHelper gets created i.e. first thing when the app starts up

Comment: It hasn't this constructor `super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION, (File)null, "DB password goes here");`

Comment: Ah then you're not using omrlite-sqlcipher, see previous answer